# Convert from 12 hour time to 24 hour time in excel

Tags: excel

I need to convert from 12 hour time to 24 hour time in excel.

I have it on this format:

11/13/2016 7:00:02 AM

I need it to be like this

11.13.2016 07:00:02

How could this be done? I have approximately 1000 cells that need to be converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates and times are stored as numbers in Excel. How these numbers show in worksheet cells is governed by formatting. If your data contains real date/time values, you don't need to convert anything.

Use formatting to display values in a different time format in the worksheet cells. The date/time will show in the formula bar according to your computer's system settings for date/time display, but that's only in the formula bar.

[image]

Use the underlying values unchanged for calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Fully agree with Teylyn - however you may want to change the display and perhaps this is what you actually meant by "conversion". To adapt the display, let's we start with this:
[image]

Select the whole range you want to display differently and you can choose from the dropdown "More number format":
[image]

Then you can go to "Custom" on the list in the left & select something like this one:

[image]

Which gives this:

[image]

Or you can use the sample to make up a display of your own (you can edit the format line to yield anything you want).

Edit: if you like the answer, please accept it.